# Variables used in Express Routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Express.js routing concepts. For example:

```
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var app = express();

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

Edit: I understand the loading of the file modules now. Which leads to a question, why not specify the filename of the module?

To clarify, the app.get in the above example specifies a function in that module correct? My questions is how does the var routes module know to load index.js in that folder? I'm still missing the connection from loading the (unspecified) module in /routes to index.js.

Comment: You're confusing functions, files, and module paths.  Start by reading http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to (hopefully) clarify. The way I read the loading of those modules is:
user = /routes/user.js, which the list function is called in app.get
routes = /routes.js, which does seem to be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the documentation I linked earlier, if you pass `require()` a path to a folder, it will look for a (JS or JSON) file named `index` inside that folder.

Comment: Oh, I see now. **If there is no package.json in the folder**, it will look for `index` in that folder. I incorrectly assumed there was a single package.json for the entire app in the root directory.

Comment: @Robert: No; Node itself (unlike npm) has no conception of "app" or "root directory".